# No! I command you to

Tags: riddle

A nice little riddle in the form of a command.

> Now write this try:
>
> Disguise in evil ones not,
>
> Lights change to flick you
>
> And with in for not eating
>
> One to not scratch means.
>
> Who am I?

Try to decipher, please try your best...
Until you post the answer, I'll never rest.

Comment: A Jack-O-Lantern!

Comment: @Spacemonkey That is incorrect, but I like it. It doesn't fit with the last line, though.

Comment: Sinistar :D hahha

Comment: It feels funny when reading backward

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost sure this is the solution, but I'm not sure my *method* was right. Nevertheless, here it is.
First, let's scramble the main part of the riddle a bit to make *some* things more coherent:

> Now not *you try to scratch this*
> Not *means evil one in disguise*
> With ones *flick to change lights*
> Not write in and *for eating*

As you can see, it still doesn't make much sense. But if we treat some of the words as *commands*:

> No W, no T: *You try to scratch this*
> No T: *Means evil one in disguise*
> With one S: *Flick to change lights*
> No T, write in 'and': *For eating*

Now they look like proper clues, all leading to one word:

> **Twitch.**
>
> No W, no T: *You try to scratch this* (**Itch**)
> No T: *Means evil one in disguise* (**Witch**)
> With one S: *Flick to change lights* (**Witch+s = Switch**)
> No T, write in 'and': *For eating* (**Switch-t+and = Sandwich**)
>
> *[Note that 'itch' is a separate clue, which is why I'm not sure I scrambled this right]*

And as for 'I'll never rest':

> You're restless when you're twitching.

Again, I'm not entirely sure I *got there* properly, but I'm fairly convinced that's the gist of it.

Comment: This is incredibly close, but not the exact answer, I feel you've taken quite a lot of liberties with the scrambling. The removal of letters is correct, but which letters are removed is not decided the way you thought it was, although I should admit that this is an incredible solution, and I'm contemplating awarding a bounty to it.

Comment: @awesomepi Yeah, figured something was missing... My logic wasn't exactly ironclad. ;) I'll try and figure it out. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 2):

> The month of March.

(although I'm not sure how it matches the last line.)

It's not the month of Halloween

Yet it's a daylight saving switching month

Which does not contain Thanksgiving

???

Comment: "Beware the Ides of March" is from *Julius Caesar*, referencing that he would (spoiler) be killed on March 15.

Comment: Could you give stone sort of explanation line by line?

Answer (score 2):

> Try

Okay, this is probably not correct, but it's at least amusing. Here we go:

I command you to

> Try. And that's what I'm doing

Now write this try:

> I did write it. I'll write it again. Try.

Disguise in evil ones not,

> Obvious reference to Yoda. Do or do not. There is no try.

Lights change to flick you

> It's very trying when lights change. It's like they are flicking you off.

And with in for not eating

> Try = test. With "in", makes intestine. And...er...okay, I don't know

One to not scratch means.

> Scratch that itch means try.

Who am I?

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> A ghost?

Now write this try:

> Many, many stories written of you

Disguise in evil ones not,

> You are very disguised (invisible to human sight) and you might be very evil sometimes.

Lights change to flick you

> What you can do is flick us humans, just to scare us. Also, changing lights are also very known in many stories and movies.

And with in for not eating

> You don't eat. You're not a zombie.

One to not scratch means.

> Besides changing lights, flicker us and creating footsteps on a stairway, you can make scratching noises on all surfaces.

Who am I?

> Bonus title: "I command you to" is a part of "The Conjuring" where the evil spirits (ghosts) are forced to reveal themselves: I COMMAND YOU TO REVEAL YOURSELF!

Comment: Nice try, but you've ignored about half of each clue.

Comment: Hehe.. Would be too easy otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> A WereWolf

Disguise in evil ones not,

> They are *disguised as innocent* people when not in werewolf form.

Lights change to flick you.

> Flick = Sudden quick movement.
> When the moon*light* comes out they become a werewolf.

And with in for not eating

> When not *eating* humans they are trapped *within* one.

One to not scratch means.

> They *dont mean* to transform, therefore they dont mean to *scratch.*

Extra:

> *Until you post the answer, I'll never rest.*
>  Werewolves are always active since human by day werewolf by night.